# How to add event listener to animated transform rotate?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

so I have a 2-faced card and everytime the card rotates 180 deg, it changes the face's value.

One thing I thought about doing is to add event listener to the animation transform rotate, but seems this is impossible?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4qovckd7/

What i'm trying to achieve is to change the face card value (the FRONT and BACK text) every 180 degrees turn.
Already tried using jquery animate step and progress, but I can't seem to get the correct value of the progress (only returns 0 or 1 which is the start and end of the animation)

```
$('.card').on('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {
  var spinValue = 5 * 180;

  if (event.handleObj.type == 'swipeleft')
    spinValue = spinValue * -1;

  $(this).animate({
    borderSpacing: spinValue
  }, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
      $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
    },
    progress: function (animation, progress, msRemaining) {
      //supposedly to get the progress value here
    }
  });
})
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: face value means the FRONT and BACK text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swipe and animation are broken. If you swipe left multiple times you'll see that transition cannot follow-up it's current degrees rotation state - with the new input.

## Solution

- Use a variable to store the *current **Original rotation** degrees* (`-N° … 0° … N°`) - which means, no matter how many times you swipe, the number will add up (or down) to the current org. degrees.
- **Normalize** your *Original degress* to a ***Relative rotation*** degrees using this formula:

```
deg = orgDeg % 360          // This still has negatives: -360° … 0° … 360°
if ( deg < 0 ) deg += 360   // Always 0° … 360°. Now you can rotateY( deg )
```

- **Get the Current face** as binary `0, 1`.
  As you might notice, a face (say the front face) does not starts at 0 degrees!
  It starts to be visible at `-90°` (now normalized to 270). Same goes for the rear face. It starts it's *"I'm visible!"* journey at  `+90°`.  If you don't follow up, imagine you want to change a face to a random image every turn, it would be silly to do it once the surface  is fully facing front.
  So, **a turn starts when a plane's Edges are facing front!** Here's the math:

```
face = round( ((deg + 90) % 360) / 360 )    // 0, 1, 0, 1, 0…
```

---

## Make things a bit more realistic

#### Perspective

Adding `perspective: 1000px;` to parent, helps visualize the card transformations in ***2D3D***.

#### Animation

Easing `swing` or `linear` (the default jQuery `.animate()` easings) do not fit like a nice `easeOutCubic`, which best describes a building-up **momentum to a natural stop**.
If you don't want to include the whole jQuery UI library, you can extend the `$.easing`

```
// https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
    easeOutCubic :function(x){return 1-Math.pow(1-x,3)}
});
```

#### Speed

Improve UX by adding **swipe speed to card rotation**. Here's a function:

```
function swipeSpeed(e) {
    var st = e.swipestart,
        sp = e.swipestop,
        time = sp.time - st.time,
        a = st.coords[0] - st.coords[1],
        b = sp.coords[0] - sp.coords[1],
        dist = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
    return dist / time;
}
```

#### Clear animation queue

In order to play **swipe back and forth**, you'll have to clear the animation queue by using `.stop()`:

```
.stop().animate({
```

#### Enough talking

```js
// https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
  easeOutCubic: function(x) {
    return 1 - Math.pow(1 - x, 3)
  }
});


function swipeSpeed(e) {
  var st = e.swipestart,
    sp = e.swipestop,
    time = sp.time - st.time,
    a = st.coords[0] - st.coords[1],
    b = sp.coords[0] - sp.coords[1],
    dist = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  return dist / time;
}


var cats = [ // cause we luw catz
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBGtG.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzdQz.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJl4g.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QAyw.jpg",
  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/updEN.jpg",
];

var $info = $("#info");
$(".card-wrapper").each(function() {

  var $card = $(this).find(".card");
  var $back = $(this).find(".card-back");
  var _d = 0;

  $(this).on({
    'swipeleft swiperight': function(e) {

      var isLeft = e.type === 'swipeleft';
      var sw = Math.min(swipeSpeed(e), 10); // Math.min to prevent excessive momentum
      var s = 180 * sw;
      var spinDegs = _d + (isLeft ? -s : s);
      spinDegs -= spinDegs % 180; // (optional) end rotation as full-face

      $card.stop().animate({
        sD: spinDegs
      }, {
        duration: 700 * sw,
        easing: "easeOutCubic",
        step: function(d) {
          _d = d; // store now for later use
          var deg = (d %= 360) < 0 ? d + 360 : d; // Degrees Normalization
          $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + deg + 'deg)'); // Rotate

          // Extra fun!
          var face = Math.round(((deg + 90) % 360) / 360);
          var idx = Math.abs(Math.round(((_d + 90) / 360)) % cats.length);
          $back.css({
            backgroundImage: `url('${cats[idx]}')`
          });
          // Show info
          $info.html(`
            Face: ${ face }<br> 
            Org Degrees: ${ _d }<br>
            Degrees: ${ deg }<br>
            Cat image: ${ idx }
          `);

        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Flipping cards */

.card-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card .card-front,
.card .card-back {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  background: 50% 50%/cover transparent none no-repeat;
}

.card .card-front {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.card .card-back {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: red;
}

#info {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* Should all go to top but yeah I'll keep it below-the-fold for this demo*/


/* QuickReset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}


/* jQueryMobile resets */

[data-role="page"] {
  outline: none;
}

.ui-loader {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-front"><span class="card-content">SWIPE</span></div>
    <div class="card-back"><span class="card-content">:)</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi thank you very much for this solution, sorry if mine was broken, i was trying to point out my issue which was changing the face thus i minimized my code. But either way you improved it drastically, thank you again. This is the best solution so far!